# Remove Info view from import/export helper

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to remove the INFO view which appears in the file browser window when I use `ImportHelper` or `ExportHelper`  when opening the file browser. I found that they are located in `/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/io_utils.py` but I'm not sure what to edit in the file so that when my operator is based on the `ImportHelper` or `ExportHelper` the INFO view don't show up.

For example this is what currently happens when I call the open file operator which uses the `ImportHelper`:

[image]

I want to remove the INFO view highlighted below so that when my operators depend on the `ExportHelper` or `ImportHelper` only the FileBrowser appears as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Quite sure you can't do this, not without some extreme hacks at least (or modifying C code). EDIT: if all you want to do is not show the buttons, you could temporarily override the header draw function (quite hacky - but would work)